# Edit tags unavailable after editing the post itself

Tags: bug, edits, inline-editor, inline-tag-editor

All users with 10k+ reputation are given access to inline `edit tags` link. This link is shown something like this(only on hovering) as shown in the image that follows.

[image]

But when I edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15586126/1190388)( https://stackoverflow.com/q/15586126/1190388 ) and decided to use the inline tag editor instead of editing using the post box itself, I did not see the `edit tags` text. This is shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Can be marked as [tag:status-completed]